# Aggregate by array items

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem with Elasticsearch aggregation query.
Data sample:

```
PUT test
POST test/customer
{
  "name": "John",
  "cities": ["NYC", "Paris"],
  "sId": 1
}
POST test/customer
{
  "name": "Steve",
  "cities": ["NYC"],
  "sId": 2
}
POST test/customer
{
  "name": "John",
  "cities": ["Paris", "Cape Town"],
  "sId": 3
}
GET test/customer/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

What I would like to get is where and how many times same person was in this format:

```
{
    key: "John_Paris",
    doc_count: 2
},
{
    key: "John_NYC",
    doc_count: 1
},  {
    key: "John_Cape Town",
    doc_count: 1
},
{
    key: "Steve_NYC",
    doc_count: 1
}
```

I'm stuck with this but it's wrong:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "duplicateCount": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "inline": "return [doc['name.keyword'].value, doc['cities.keyword'].value].join('_')"
        },
        "size": 2000000000,
        "min_doc_count": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It returns:

```
{
  "key": "John_Cape Town",
  "doc_count": 1
},
{
  "key": "John_NYC",
  "doc_count": 1
},
{
  "key": "Steve_NYC",
  "doc_count": 1
}
```

and there is no John_Paris item included:

```
{
    key: "John_Paris",
    doc_count: 2
}
```

How to achieve that?

Thanks in advance

### UPDATE

So, the ANSWER for me keeping the result in intended format was to create an array with keys and return it within the script's `inline`, like so:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "duplicateCount": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "inline": "def keys = []; for (p in doc['cities.keyword'].values) { keys.add(doc['name.keyword'].value + '_'  + p);} return keys;"
        },
        "size": 2000000000,
        "min_doc_count": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can nest your aggregation. It will give you the results in a different format, but analogous to it.
Try this:

```
{
   "aggs":{
      "name":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"name.keyword"
         },
         "aggs":{
            "cities":{
               "terms":{
                  "field":"cities.keyword"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: hm.. I'm getting `unknown BaseAggregationBuilder [term]`. What I'm doing wrong do you think?

Comment: It should have been "terms" - I fixed it - perhaps there's something - I wrote this without testing

Comment: yeah, you missed an `"agg"` for `"cities"` and add `.keyword` for both fields. Do you know how to transform it to have the output close to example in the question maybe (with composite key)?

Comment: I fixed the answers. No I don't, but I'm guessing it can do done with painless similar to the query in the question. I would suggest providing the output of your query and explaining why it's wrong